# One-to-one relationship realm with the new Live Inverse Relationships

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a a class similar to this:

```
class Flight: Object {

dynamic var flightNumber = ""
dynamic var departureApt = ""
dynamic var arrivalApt = ""

dynamic var nextFlight : Flight?
dynamic var previousFlight : Flight?

}
```

A 'flight' may contain nextFlight and/or previousFlight, but it is not guaranteed. My goal is to query for a flight and check if it is a child of another flight (either next or previous of a parent flight).

Before Realm 0.100 i retrieved the parent by using this code:

```
if let parent = flight.linkingObjects(Flight.self, forProperty: "previousFlight").first {
      print("This flight has a parent flight: \(parent.flightNumber)")
}
```

I am now unsure how to achieve the same with Realm 0.100 and would love some feedback!

**EDIT**

I have now been able to achieve the result I wanted, but I am not sure if it is the correct way to do it. I have added a variable that finds the parent this way:

```
let parentForNext = LinkingObjects(fromType: Flight.self, property: "nextFlight")
let parentForPrevious = LinkingObjects(fromType: Flight.self, property: "previousFlight")

var parent : Flight? {

    get {

        return parentForNext.first ?? parentForPrevious.first ?? nil

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Object.linkingObjects(_:property:)` method was deprecated in Realm Swift 0.100 (see [release post](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.100.0/) for more).

This is because there's a more powerful (though slightly more verbose) way to declare inverse relationships in Realm: through the `LinkingObjects` property type on models. This allows linking objects to behave like live, auto-updating `List` properties or `Results` queries. So you know the objects you get back will never be out of date, which is especially important given that all other Realm types auto-update. It also allows querying inverse relationships as if they were forward relationships (`List` properties).

So if you did this before 0.100:

```
let parent = flight.linkingObjects(Flight.self, forProperty: "previousFlight").first
```

The equivalent is this in 0.100 and later (on the model):

```
let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Flight.self, property: "previousFlight")
var parent: Flight? { return parents.first }
```

In your second code sample, you have multiple "parents", and yes you can have a computed property that combines them in whatever way you like:

```
let nextParent = LinkingObjects(fromType: Flight.self, property: "nextFlight")
let previousParent = LinkingObjects(fromType: Flight.self, property: "previousFlight")
var parent: Flight? { return nextParent.first ?? previousParent.first }
```

You can read more about inverse relationships in Realm's docs on the subject: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships